I have a problem using AutoMapper when grouping data
I have a problem with mapping and was hoping somebody could please advise. I am using the latest .NET and C#, I am querying the database for values and then want to map to my Dto in a particular structure.
The data I want to return is below (I can retrieve this fine in Ef process) and it is grouped by Person Id:
Id, PersonId, BodyPart, ProblemNotes
1, 200, Arm, Sore bicep
2, 200, Arm, Pulled tricep
3, 201, Leg, Hamstring strain

My Ef class representation of the above table is this:
Id
PersonId
virtual List<Issue>

The Issue class:
Id
BodyPart
ProblemNotes

I would like to display these results in the following Dto:
PersonId,
List<Issue>

The Issue class consists of:
BodyPart,
ProblemNotes

The problem I have is the mapping part. In my MappingProfile class, I can setup the Issue mapping fields fine but since the Person Id is at a higher level and should be grouped, I don't know how to map this.
Do I have to manually map this in code somehow? Group by PersonId and then loop through, etc?

In your mapping profile you can write custom function and use it during the mapping. So yes, you need to map it manually.
